# how can i invoke a method when variable value change

Tags: c#, web-services

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
 using System.Net;


 namespace CS_Ex1
 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
   private string tb1, tb2;
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }

  private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      WSMBT.Result Result;
      wsmbtControl1.Mode = WSMBT.Mode.TCP_IP;
      wsmbtControl1.ResponseTimeout = 1000;
      Result = wsmbtControl1.Connect("127.0.0.1", 502);
      if (Result != WSMBT.Result.SUCCESS)
          MessageBox.Show(wsmbtControl1.GetLastErrorString());
  }

  private void Disconnect_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      wsmbtControl1.Close();
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Int16[] Registers = new Int16[20];
      WSMBT.Result Result;
      Result = wsmbtControl1.ReadHoldingRegisters(1, 0, 20, Registers);
      if (Result == WSMBT.Result.SUCCESS)
      {
          string DataString = "";
          string str = "";

          for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
          {
              str = string.Format("{0:D}", Registers[0]);
              str = string.Format("{0:D}", Registers[1]);

              DataString = DataString + str + "\r\n";
          }
          TextBox1.Text = Registers[0].ToString();
          TextBox2.Text = Registers[1].ToString();


           tb1 = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
          tb2 = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
          }
      else
      {
          MessageBox.Show(wsmbtControl1.GetLastErrorString());
      }

  }

  private void Write_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Int16[] Registers = new Int16[20];
      WSMBT.Result Result;
      for (Int16 i = 0; i < 20; i++)
          Registers[i] = i;
      Result = wsmbtControl1.WriteMultipleRegisters(1, 0, 20, Registers);
      if (Result != WSMBT.Result.SUCCESS)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(wsmbtControl1.GetLastErrorString());
      }
  }

  public static void message_Click()
  {
      string senderusername = "XXX";
      string senderpassword = "XXXX";
      string senderid = "22687";
      string sURL;
      StreamReader objReader;
      sURL = "URL";
      WebRequest wrGETURL;
      wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
      try
      {
          Stream objStream;
          objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
          objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
          objReader.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          ex.ToString();
      }
  }
  }


}
```

In this Code VARIABLE tb1 is getting change all the time i want to invoke message_click() method which will send sms to user mobile  when tb1 value gets change or suppose its value was 10 and then tb1 value changed to 68 then it should invoke message_click () and send sms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a property for this. In the setter you can call the desired method after the variable has been changed:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private tb2;
    private string _tb1;

    public string tb1
    {
        get { return _tb1; }
        private set
        {
            _tb1 = value;
            message_click();
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Note that although the property is `public` you can make the setter private so that the variable cannot be changed outside of this class. You could also use `protected`:

```
protected string tb1
{ ...
```

Comment: can u please put it in code i have try this but nothing comes so far perhaps i am making mistake somewhere

Comment: @R-T I made a mistake! You need to change this line `tb1 = value;` to `_tb1 = value;` otherwise you will get a StackOverflow exception. I corrected it in my post. Now it works. I tested it

Comment: @R-T still no luck in making it work?

Comment: its working @Mong Zhu but there is a problem i m looking on it i will discuss with you

Comment: why not, go ahead. If my answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted in the meanwhile ;)

Comment: its not working sms is triggered every time do u have skype i have to chat with u on some options

Comment: can we store a value in a variable when the program gets close

Comment: @R-T click on the `continue this discussion in chat` link in my comment, and we can chat

Comment: @R-T you can store the value, but it will be gone after the program has closed. If you want to save it, you have to write it into a file or something. I see you haven't accepted any of the answers from all your questions. [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) might help